# Crash in libdispatch _dispatch_semaphore_wait_slow

Tags: crash, libdispatch

I sometimes get a crash deep inside libdispatch with the following backtrace stemming from the `SecItemCopyMatching` function.

```
* thread #1: tid = 0x169ee8, 0x0374c830 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_semaphore_wait_slow + 278, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread, stop reason = EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)
    frame #0: 0x0374c830 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_semaphore_wait_slow + 278
    frame #1: 0x0374c711 libdispatch.dylib`dispatch_semaphore_wait + 37
    frame #2: 0x03921b54 libxpc.dylib`xpc_connection_send_message_with_reply_sync + 231
    frame #3: 0x01448e99 Security`securityd_message_with_reply_sync + 78
    frame #4: 0x01449098 Security`securityd_send_sync_and_do + 81
    frame #5: 0x01459926 Security`__SecItemCopyMatching_block_invoke + 218
    frame #6: 0x014589f9 Security`SecOSStatusWith + 37
    frame #7: 0x014597da Security`SecItemCopyMatching + 208
    frame #8: 0x0022b482 MyApp`+[BITKeychainUtils getPasswordForUsername:andServiceName:error:](self=0x00399e3c, _cmd=0x002d21e0, username=0x003a336c, serviceName=0x0c17c420, error=0xbfffeb24) + 738 at BITKeychainUtils.m:63
    frame #9: 0x00221eff MyApp`-[BITHockeyBaseManager stringValueFromKeychainForKey:](self=0x0c1b6400, _cmd=0x002d2322, key=0x003a336c) + 175 at BITHockeyBaseManager.m:297
    frame #10: 0x001ef2c2 MyApp`-[BITAuthenticator publicInstallationIdentifier](self=0x0c1b6400, _cmd=0x002d2678) + 194 at BITAuthenticator.m:749
    frame #11: 0x00228be1 MyApp`-[BITHockeyManager startManager](self=0x0c6a1e90, _cmd=0x002d2358) + 865 at BITHockeyManager.m:196
    frame #12: 0x00090ed4 MyApp`-[ApplicationDelegate init](self=0x0c1850e0, _cmd=0x0375f96b) + 212 at ApplicationDelegate.m:86
    frame #13: 0x01583cde UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 1132
    frame #14: 0x00002e32 MyApp`main(argc=1, argv=0xbfffee74) + 178 at main.m:15
```

This crash seems totally random, it never happens to my coworkers. It mainly happens in the 32-bit iOS simulator but it also occurred once on a device.

I have looked at [libdispatch source code](https://github.com/aosm/libdispatch/blob/master/src/semaphore.c#L375) and I can see that a crash may happen like this: `_dispatch_semaphore_wait_slow()` → `DISPATCH_SEMAPHORE_VERIFY_KR` → `DISPATCH_CRASH` → `_dispatch_hardware_crash()` → `__builtin_trap()` but I don’t really understand why that’s happening.

Does anyone know what’s going on?

**Edit**: the same crash also happened when running unit tests with the following backtrace:

```
* thread #1: tid = 0x544131, 0x0375a830 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_semaphore_wait_slow + 278, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread, stop reason = EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)
    frame #0: 0x0375a830 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_semaphore_wait_slow + 278
    frame #1: 0x0375a711 libdispatch.dylib`dispatch_semaphore_wait + 37
    frame #2: 0x0392fb54 libxpc.dylib`xpc_connection_send_message_with_reply_sync + 231
    frame #3: 0x0153c20a SystemConfiguration`__SCNetworkReachabilityServer_targetStatus + 234
    frame #4: 0x015143ce SystemConfiguration`__SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags + 415
    frame #5: 0x015122a0 SystemConfiguration`reachPerform + 305
    frame #6: 0x0344583f CoreFoundation`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 15
    frame #7: 0x03445295 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 437
    frame #8: 0x0346229e CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 910
    frame #9: 0x03461ac3 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
    frame #10: 0x034618db CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    frame #11: 0x050b79e2 GraphicsServices`GSEventRunModal + 192
    frame #12: 0x050b7809 GraphicsServices`GSEventRun + 104
    frame #13: 0x01591d3b UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 1225
    frame #14: 0x000030ea Test Host`main(argc=10, argv=0xbfffeae0) + 138 at main.m:15
```

Comment: Hey Cédric, can you supply the full crash log?

Comment: It only happens when I debug in Xcode, so I’m just stuck on a `ud2` instruction and no crash log is generated. Or is there a way to let the program continue and generate a full crash log?

Comment: fwiw (das already having addressed the issue), 'register read' and 'image list' in LLDB will provide most of what matters in the report, in addition to the above.

Comment: It happened again, so here are the [registers and image list dump](http://pastebin.com/sRc5mrpb).

Comment: that value of eax is definitely unexpected, c.f. comment below.

Comment: It happened again, with a different backtrace and [on the device](http://pastebin.com/Q3HHb8CM) this time.

Answer (score 4):

When hitting this type of assertion on x86_64, the rax register contains the error code returned from the kernel syscall.

You should be able to inspect that value from the debugger console via `reg read`. Detaching the debugger from the process after hitting the exception should also generate a crashreport (which you may want to [file](http://bugreport.apple.com)).

Unfortunately I don't think the rax trick works on i386 so you may need to retrieve the syscall return value via a breakpoint before hitting the assertion.

In this case the syscall is `semaphore_wait` and the error is most likely going to be 0xf, i.e. `KERN_INVALID_NAME` (c.f. /usr/include/mach/kern_return.h)

Hitting that error is an indication of one of the following (in order of likelihood):

- over-release/user-after-free of a dispatch semaphore object
- heap memory corruption
- mach port mismanagement in the process

Comment: eax is `0xffffffdc` in your dump, that is actually the syscall number of the `semaphore_wait` trap (c.f. disassembly of `_semaphore_wait_trap` symbol in `libsystem_kernel.dylib`), i.e. what eax is set to before the `sysenter` instruction. Having that input register returned unchanged from the `sysenter` is a sign the syscall wasn't performed at all, e.g. unexpectedly interrupted by an exception. You are definitely in bug-filing territory here, please file a radar with instructions on how to reproduce!